# Conflicting spring beans from different tomcat webapps

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I have two spring webapps on Tomcat.
Both are same apps with different versions.

When i run tomcat it catches error:

```
SEVERE [localhost-startStop-2] org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext
Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: 
Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/spring.xml];
nested exception is org.springframework.context.annotation.ConflictingBeanDefinitionException:
Annotation-specified bean name 'userService' for bean class 
 [ru.ommega.service.rest.UserService] conflicts with existing, non-compatible
 bean definition of same name and class [ru.ommega.service.UserService]
```

my spring.xml has the following code:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="ru.ommega.dao"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="ru.ommega.service"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="ru.ommega"/>
```

both classes are kept in different wars, so how can they conflict?

versions:

```
 Tomcat 8.0.14
 Spring 4.3.7
```

sorry for possible bad english

Comment: *same apps with different versions* you mean same application name ??

Comment: Your last component-scan covers everything in the `ru.ommega` package and all sub packages. So if you also have a `ru.ommega.service.rest.` in your war.jar that will as well be scanned.

Comment: @Ravi application names are different in tomcat. I mean i have 6-months-old build and current build of one project.

Comment: @M.Deinum it should be scanned, because in latter version i moved class in a package. I also changed it a lot. And it still have same task, so i didn't rename it.
So i have `ru.ommega.service.UserService` in first application and `ru.ommega.service.rest.UserService` classes in other

Comment: @M.Deinum i also see now that i can leave only `ru.ommega` scan, but it never have conflicts while running alone or with applications made from other projects or with itself same version, just old and new ones will conflict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

What i did before:

- `mvn package` first version
- `git checkout` needed branch
- `mvn package` second version

What i needed before every `mvn package`

- intellij idea import maven changes
- intellij idea synchronize (`ctrl`+`alt`+`y`)
- `mvn clean`